# Which AVD Target is the right one for a Droid X2?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am a [noob](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noob) to Android (and Java).  I have successfully setup Eclipse and the Android Virtual Device (AVD).  I am guessing the AVD's Target is the version of Android to be emulated, but I want to make sure. I am trying to develop something for my Droid X2 phone.

**As such...**

1. Which AVD Target is the right one for a Droid X2?
2. Is there an online list  someplace explaining each Target?

...I have Googled both unsuccessfully.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to motorolas website, the Droid X2 ships with Android 2.2 (api level 8).
I'm not sure if there are any updates rolled out yet, so consider this the lowest version you will get for this device.

So target 2.2. or lower.

*But just a general advice:* If you want to ship your app to other people, it's usually best to target the broadest audience. So I recommend going for 1.6 as a target, that will still run on your phone. You can start to raise the target version when you notice that you need a certain feature (can be easily done from the "project properties" dialog inside eclipse in 5 seconds). If you don't seem to need any higher api features, you are way more compatible to many more devices this way.

Edit: To the targets. See [Android API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). Clicking on a version takes you to the changelog. Theres info whats new. Also notice that anything below and equal 2.3.3 is a phone os at the moment. Anything equal or above 3.0 is a tablet os.

Comment: Is there a way to view how popular any given target is?  Where would I get that info?

Comment: The android developers site has a stat based on 14-day periods of devices that access the android market. That may be the most accurate thing you can get: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: @Prisoner ZERO : u may find the info regarding it from the developer.motorola.com